# Визуальное выделение текста

Tags: jquery

Многоуважаемый all. Подскажите, плз, возможно ли реализовать на jQuery, и\или используя плагины такое выделение, как на снимке?

[image: выделение текста]

Answer (score 2):

Да, конечно возможно. 
Вкратце, для этого нужно определить в каком блоке мы производим выделение(onclick), в том числе, координаты клика относительно блока.
Потом получить символы выделения

```
//Grab selected text
function getSelectedText(){ 
    if(window.getSelection){ 
        return window.getSelection().toString(); 
    } 
    else if(document.getSelection){ 
        return document.getSelection(); 
    } 
    else if(document.selection){ 

        return document.selection.createRange().text; 
    } 
}
```

Затем определить начало верхней строки текста блока(с учетом margin, padding, line-height). 
Далее производится поиск по блоку выделенного фрагмента. Тот, который ближе всего к координатам клика, вероятно нужный нам.

P.S. более простой способ - разбить текст на спаны (в статичной верстке - на строки) и отлавливать selection на каждом из них. Преимущество - более точное определение координатов.
[StackOverflow:getSelectedText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577756/selection-position-of-selected-text-of-div-using-javascript)